# how do i remove the extra white space in my website

Tags: html, css

On my website, it keeps adding extra white space on the right side

I can't figure out how to remove it, I tried the margin padding, and it didn't work 
if it's a problem with my code, then here is the code for the images and styles

```css
div.box {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -1250px;
  margin-top: -225px;
}


/* applied for all images, e.g box2, box3, box4*/
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/76/d8/03/76d80307e603191188e9e7faac52bed3.jpg" alt="cute cat">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+debug+margin*+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: I'm very sure you don't need any of these negative margins. What design are you trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: @cloned i'm trying to align all 4 pictures to all 4 corners

Comment: Use `position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0` for the top left image. adjust left, top (or bottom) for other 3 images.

Answer (score 0):

Use the overflow css property:

```
div.ex1 {
  overflow: scroll;
}

div.ex2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.ex3 {
  overflow: auto;
}

div.ex4 {
  overflow: clip;
}

div.ex5 {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Try overflow: x or overflow: y

Comment: it works, but it sets all the images to the center, I'm aiming to set all the images to all 4 corners, thanks for helping

Comment: maybe try html { overflow: y} in your css

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `padding` & `margin` property.

---

```css
.box {
  padding: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
}

.box img {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/76/d8/03/76d80307e603191188e9e7faac52bed3.jpg" alt="cute cat">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `padding` to your code.

```
div.box {
  padding:0;
  ...
}
div.box img{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try writing some css for image ,
to make a image responsive we use

img {width : 100%;}

this will tell image to take full width of div..